# Redirect rule to php query but remove any query string in the requested url

Tags: php, .htaccess

My url is being redirected using .htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^b/([^/]+)/([^/]+)? b/view.php?id=$2&name=$1
```

Friendly url -> translates to php url

`domain.com/b/hello/2 -> b/view.php?id=2&name=hello`

BUT when someone comes to the site as follows:

`domain.com/b/hello/2?query=xyz`

I don't know how to get rid of the `?query=xyz`

I have tried everything including [QSD] and I can't seem to get it to work.

**Update**

I have managed to get it to work with the following but it does two 301 redirects instead of one:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?[^\ ]+
RewriteRule ^b/(.*)$ /x/$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^b/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ b/view.php?id=$2&&name=$1
```

Comment: Do you really want to get rid of the additional parameter or do you want to pass on all additional parameters to the `view.php` file as well?

Comment: I would like to get rid of the ?query=xyz so domain.com/b/hello/2?query=xyz becomes domain.com/b/hello/2 where id=$2 and name=$1 is passed to php

Comment: This is not what your RewriteRule does. I guess you want it to be `view.php?id=2&name=hello`?! Or you want to hide the query from the user? Because the RewriteRule handles the additional parameter quite well, but it will stay in the URL in your Browser. To fix this, you need an additional rule which redirects  the user in case any GET parameter is present.

Comment: Exactly, so first redirect domain.com/b/hello/2?query=xyz needs to be come domain.com/b/hello/2 and then map that to the php file. I am just not sure how to do that.

Comment: [From comments on an answer] _“This for SEO purposes where the search engines think there is duplicate content because of query strings.”_ - then specify the _canonical URL_ correctly in your meta tags, and they will stop thinking that …

Answer (score 0):

Check if adding the question mark at the end of the rule will cancel appending query string from left side

```
RewriteRule ^b/([^/]+)/([^/]+)? b/view.php?id=$2&name=$1? [QSD,L]
```

Comment: Just tried this and it didn't work. The ?query=xyz is still on the end. This for SEO purposes where the search engines think there is duplicate content because of query strings. I am trying to 301 redirect without the ?query=xyz on the end while still keeping the user friendly url (and variables) included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional Rule to catch for GET parameters and strip them off.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^b/([^/]+)/([^/]+)? b/view.php?id=$2&name=$1
```

To make it only work on the `/b/` subfolder, use this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^b/(.*)$ b/$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^b/([^/]+)/([^/]+)? b/view.php?id=$2&name=$1
```

The first rule will redirect everything that matches your rule to the URL without any GET parameters (note the `?` at the end of the rewrite rule, it will strip off the parameters).

The second rule will match in the case the first rule cannot be applied, i.e., when there are no paramaters

Comment: The only issue is will this only be applied to urls in the /b/ folder? or will this affect other urls. Does this solve the problem of two redirects?

Comment: This will apply to all URLs, but I edited my answer to work only on the /b/ subfolder. It will do one 301 redirect.